# Error: Visual Basic .NET compiler not found (Mono 2.6.7) (First MonoNet App)

Tags: vb.net, monodevelop

I just installed MonoDevelop so that I could develop .net apps on by Ubuntu partition.

Nothing will compile because of the following error:

```
Error: Visual Basic .NET compiler not found (Mono 2.6.7) (First MonoNet App)
```

I did a quick Google search and found nothing on how to fix the problem?  Where do I get a Mono .NET Compiler...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `sudo apt-get install monodevelop mono-vbnc` from the Terminal prompt to install the VB.net compiler

Comment: Note that this only applies to systems using the Debian package manager. That includes Debian and Ubuntu, amongst others. Otherwise, you'll need to find out how to install packages on your system.